# PHP and window.close in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have a problem. I have a page that when you click a button, a popup with a form is shown. So, I complete some data and I submit. What I want to do is, to submit the form, close the form and refresh the parent page. I don't want to do it with AJAX.

The problem is that in my parent page I have to refresh content with the input information of the form.

So when I refresh, sometimes the data is shown and sometimes not. Do you know why this could happen?

I just use `onsubmit="refreshParent()"` in my form. The info is stored always in my database, so I think the problem may be that sometimes the refresh catches the new info and sometimes not.

```
function refreshParent() {    
    window.opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where this has anything to do with PHP as currently written, nor does the minimal JavaScript code you've provided really help us troubleshoot anything.

Comment: i think this could be happening because the event on the client fires before the post to the server, but the behavior will ultimately be async for this case. Maybe you want to change your form on the pop-up to return something that confirms the data was saved and then change your refreshParent function to be fired when this form loads if and only if you have a confirmation that a succesful post has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to reload the page that opened a popup window:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
 <!--
 function reloadParentPage() {
     window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
     if (window.opener.progressWindow) {
         window.opener.progressWindow.close()
     }
     window.close();
 }
 //-->
 </script>
```

By the way, the code above is called by a link or button in the popup page.

Comment: @MaximilianoPoggio : glad to have helped! just one thing.. would you mind sharing how you got ajax to help you get your results with the javascript for page reloading? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a race condition between the script doing the insert and the script reloading the parent.

The solution is to call refreshParent on the page after the submit - that way you know the data is in the database. You don't even have to do it on document ready - return a stub page that just defines and calls refreshParent in the head tag.

Comment: that's pretty much what i said.. should have written as an answer.. vote up

Answer (score 0):

In PHP when you run post script, at the end, include this code :

```
echo '<html><script language="javascript">
      parent.location.href="http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'"; // or any other url
      </script></html>';
```

This will output a javascript that will reload the windows.