# Reloading/Refreshing a page from a popup window

Tags: php, ajax

Let's say we have a main form, call it index.php. In this form contains a line of content with a link next to it saying rate me.:

tomatoes rate_me(as a link)

Now when the user clicks the rate me link, I'm thinking of opening up a popup window which would contain something simple for them to rate the item. This rating is updated to the Database.

In addition, when a user enters index.php, if for a link it's already rated they will see:

tomatoes review_your_rating(as a link)

Now all of the above I have working perfectly. However is it possible that when the user enters the rating in the popup box (which is updating perfectly), somehow I could refresh the index.php (main window)? The reason I would want to do this is when they rate, they should immeditely see:
tomatoes review_your_rating(as a link)   and not

tomatoes rate_me(as a link)

In other words, I want to refresh the index.php from the popup window. Is this possible?

Comment: Try checking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229230/php-and-window-close-javascript/8229623#8229623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the child window does not load content from another domain, you should be able to use the window.opener property to access the parent window. Something along the lines of:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```